# How to find where an application is storing data?

Tags: file-management, data-recovery, sniffing

I have been using this program for a long time
http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/tbone/stickynotes.html

I installed it on a new system and I need to find where it saves information so I can restore my stickies from a backup.

Is there *any* way to find out where an application writes data? I'm thinking some kind of low-level listener or file sniffer or something?

Comment: Is this not the same question? http://superuser.com/questions/158753/where-does-windows-vista-store-registry-data-on-the-hard-drive

Comment: @xavierjazz: it appears both questions are related to the same root problem, yes, but no, they are two separate questions.

Comment: @Xavierjazz, I ran into that second question after asking this first one. Procmon showed me that the subject application was storing data in the registry. Question 2 is: Where does Windows keep the registry? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procmon from Sysinternals (Microsoft) shows you the files (and registry keys) that running applications have open.

You can find it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

All modern OS have a default location where programs are supposed to store data that is created on behalf of a user.

On Windows, it's under %APPDATA% for files internal to the application (i.e. files the user should not access directly, such as internal preferences), and %USERPROFILE% for the user's data.

The actual location of these folders depends on OS version and system config, but usually it's:

%APPDATA%  : C:\Documents and Settings{username}\Application Data
%USERPROFILE% : C:\Documents and Settings{username}

Look into theses folders, probably the program stores its stuff in some subfolder there.